# How do I decrypt a Java-DES-encrypted message using openssl?

Tags: java, openssl, des

Since the question title is self-explaining, please consider the following code:

```java
private static final String ALGORITHM = "DES";
private static final String MESSAGE = "This is an extremely secret message";
private static final byte[] key = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

...

// Do encryption
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
cipher.init(ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, ALGORITHM));
final byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(MESSAGE.getBytes());

// Copy the encrypted message to a file
final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(encrypted);
final OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("___SECRET");
copy(inputStream, outputStream);
```

Now I'm trying to decrypt the `___SECRET` file with the following command:

```
openssl enc -d -des -K 0001020304050607 -iv 0 -in ___SECRET -out ___OPEN
```

which results in:

```
bad decrypt
3073636028:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:539:
```

just decrypting the very first block (8 bytes) leaving the rest in trash state (OEM encoding):

```
This is MЕ$S6%@╢Т√°ў╝°╢]∙iь
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I decrypt the encrypted message using `openssl`?

Comment: @jww: Aside from the minor difference in algorithm, 11783062 is about encrypting with openssl's default PBE which is indeed EVP_BytesToKey; this is about encrypting with key **NOT PBE**, which is a MAJOR difference. The PBE solution there is completely wrong here. A **better dupe** is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354200/blowfish-encrypt-in-java-scala-and-decrypt-in-bash although the earlier answer by Robert is already correct.

Comment: OP: do be aware that hardware improvements made **DES insecure** more than 20 years ago and it should not be used for any security purpose. _Triple_ DES, designated DESede in Java for historical reasons, is still aceeptably secure but other algorithms especially AES afe better.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yes, I'm aware of DES weakness. My question was a sort of a result of some reverse engineering, so `openssl` use is supposed for scripting only. Thank you for the comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Java you use DES in ECB mode and on OpenSSL you use DES in CBC mode (IV is present).

This is a significant difference as in CBC the blocks are chained - therefore the first block is decrypted correctly but all following blocks are scrambled.

You can change the Java part to use "DES/CBC" mode instead and provide an IV or change the openssl part and use `-des-ecb` instead of `-des`.

Comment: It works like a charm! I have to learn it more because I feel ashamed of not knowing these simple things. Thank you very much!